# Is there a way to determine if the Microsoft XPS Document Writer is available and functional on the System

Tags: c#, .net, xps

Is there a reliable way to determine if the Microsoft XPS Document Writer is available and functional on the System via .Net?

Also, is the name of the XPS Writer the same on all Windows Distributions (eg. English, German (...))?

Is the XPS Writer definately available on all Windows Systems since Vista. Also on Starter Editions, all x86 and x64 Editions and also on Windows 8?

Comment: The name is definitely not reliable. The user can rename the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" print queue any time they wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772.aspx

I suspect you could use the snippet below to try and print the XPS, then if it doesn't work, you probably do not have a printer.

```
            try
            {
                // Print the Xps file while providing XPS validation and progress notifications.
                PrintSystemJobInfo xpsPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob(f.Name, nextFile, false);
            }
            catch (PrintJobException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t{0} could not be added to the print queue.", f.Name);
                if (e.InnerException.Message == "File contains corrupted data.")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tIt is not a valid XPS file. Use the isXPS Conformance Tool to debug it.");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\tContinuing with next XPS file.\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the name, but the model of the "printer" is also Microsoft XPS Document Writer and that will remain the same.

You could just look for the printer with that model!

Comment: It looks like the model is actually the name of the printer driver, which can be obtained through PrintQueue.QueueDriver.Name.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pieter Witvoet, here is a method that return if a XPSPrinter is installed or not based on the driver name.

The method loop through printer until it find one or it has scanned every single one without finding one.
Reference to "System.Management" need to be added to the project.

```
    private bool GetIfXPSPrinterIsInstalled()
    {
        bool isXPSPrinterMissing = true;
        try
        {               
            var printerQuery = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
            var iterator = printerQuery.Get().GetEnumerator();
            while (iterator.MoveNext() && isXPSPrinterMissing )
            {
                //isXPSPrinterMissing = iterator.Current.GetPropertyValue("DriverName").ToString() != "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
                isXPSPrinterMissing = !iterator.Current.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString().ToUpper().Contains("XPS");
            }
            if (isXPSPrinterMissing )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Warning, there is no XPS printer installed on this computer");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("System couldn't verify if there is a XPS printer installed because an error occured");             
        }
        return !isXPSPrinterMissing;
    }
```

**EDIT :** I found out that driver name can be wrong some time. It may be "Remote Desktop Easy Print" instead for the XPS printer and some others non xps printer. Therefore, checking if DeviceID contains XPS is a safer way.